# operator<< overload (just) for std::stringstream dervied class

Tags: c++

I'm implementing a logging class which uses stream operators. The basic idea is that custom types can implement an `operator<<` to provide a readable representation for logging. The logging class will 'collect' various messages and forwards them (to syslog or whatever) as a single logging entry on destruction.

```
class log_stream : public std::ostringstream
{
    inline ~log_stream()
    {
        forward_to_log(str().c_str());
    }
};

class custom_type
{
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const custom_type &)
{
    stream << "<custom_type data>";
    return stream;
}

log_stream() << "error in custom type: " << custom_type_variable;
```

This works actually quite well except if the statement does not start with an overload from std::ostream but a custom type directly instead:

```
log_stream() << custom_type_variable; // no known conversion from 'log_stream'
                                      // to 'basic_ostream<char, ...>&
                                      // for 1st argument
```

And now I wonder why, because `log_stream` is-a `ostringstream` is-a `basic_ostringstream` is-a `basic_ostream`. Any ideas?

In addition: is there any way to provide the `operator<<` overloads for `log_stream&` directly and not for `std::ostream` (in case one wants two different overloads for logging - used with `log_stream` - and for example serializing to a disk - used with `fstream`)?

**EDIT #1**

If an 'r-value capable' `operator<<` is added the first problem is solved.

```
template <typename Type> inline log_stream &operator<<(log_stream &&stream, Type&& type)
{
    return operator<<(stream, std::forward<Type>(type));
}
```

However it now/still breaks on the type conversion to the base class (be it `ostringstream` or `ostream`).

```
log_stream() << custom_type(); // OK
log_stream() << custom_type() << "text"; // OK

log_stream() << "next"; // non-const lvalue reference to type 'log_stream' cannot bind
                        // to a value of unrelated type 'basic_ostream<char, ...>'
```

Why is the `basic_ostream<char, ...>` type unrelated? It *is* a base class of `log_stream` and it *should* be possible to get a reference to this base class here, shouldn't it?

**EDIT #2**

Well, it should of course call the member `operator<<`, which makes it work.

```
template <typename Type> inline log_stream &operator<<(log_stream &&stream, Type&& type)
{
    stream << std::forward<Type>(type);
    return stream;
}
```

So the problem is solved for C++11 - but it still doesn't work for C++03 (*argh*).

One solution that comes into mind is to provide a 'r-value to l-value connversion operator', in its shortest form the `operator()`.

```
class log_stream
{
    inline log_stream &()() 
    {
        return *this;
    }
}

log_stream()() << custom_type() << "text";
```

Not pretty, but something. Any better (more pretty) ideas?

Comment: You should derive from `streambuf`, not a stream type.  Read http://gabisoft.free.fr/articles/fltrsbf1.html

Comment: This has no effect on the actual problem.

Comment: Ad additional (edit) question: The return type of `stream << type` is `basic_ostream`, so you need to perform a `static_cast` back to your derived type. Like: `return static_cast<log_stream&> ( stream << std::forward<Type>(type) );`

Comment: IIRC it shouldn't be necessary to use perfect forwarding here, since the second argument shouldn't be changed by `<<` (const ref).

Comment: D'uh. It is of course a *derived* class, not a *base class*. So it needs the static_cast, yes! ;)

Comment: @std::forward: well, the operator<< might be defined as taking a value or a reference and not a const reference, which will create a copy then if it isn't std::forward'ed wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, but look at the pre-defined `operator<<` [member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) and [non-member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2). There are more IIRC, I'll look them up.

Comment: I guess there's only one that might alter the inserted object's state, but it takes the object (streambuf) by pointer. As `operator<<` does not take ownership of an object, moving is not necessary. Note there's also a generic r-value inserter, [ostream.rvalue], which takes by `T const&`. AFAIK it's sufficient to only take const refs; if not you can provide an additional version which takes non-const refs. Or break C++03 compatibility and use perfect forwarding.

Comment: As for the "prettier idea": You could wrap the `ostringstream` (as data member) instead of deriving; make the data member `mutable` and define your insertion `operator<<` as `log_stream const& operator<<(log_stream const&, T const&);`.

Answer (score 2):

Your log stream is a *temporary*, while insertion operators require a *non-const reference*. You cannot convert the former to the latter.

You have to introduce an actual named variable of type `log_stream` and use it as the left operand of `<<`.

Comment: Why should it be a const reference? The temporary is valid and modifiable until the semicolon. However the problem is indeed that it is an r-value (whereas to operator<< overload requires an l-value). But I do *not* want to give it a name as it would not be destructed until it goes out of scope then.

Comment: @T.Carter: The temporary (rvalue) is indeed modifiable, you can e.g. call non-const member functions on it. Nevertheless you cannot convert it to a non-const reference, because the standard says so. Such is life.